# Add X results in Database after Y seconds

Tags: php

How can I add, for example, 1.000 results of 12,000 in total each 5 seconds in Database?

I see about `sleep()` but I thinks will not work properly, because in theory, he add all rows after 5 seconds. So, maybe I need to do some adjustments.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "in 5 in 5 seconds" mean?

Comment: Do you mean that every 5 seconds you should add 5 results, until you finish adding all 1,000?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add 100 results within 5 seconds?

Comment: I edit the question!

Comment: Out of interest - why do you want to do this? (Barmar's answer looks like a pretty good solution)

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_chunk` to split your data into chunks of 1,000. Then loop over the chunks, insert all the data in that chunk, and sleep 5 seconds.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($data, 1000);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    foreach ($chunk as $row) {
        // insert $row into table
    }
    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: I'll try that! Thank you so much.